# Sql join 4 tables count rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables in similar form. Structures of these tables are like:

```
id  team_id position_id  country_id
1       1     1              3
2       1     1              3
3       2     2              3
4       3     3              3
```

I can count rows of one table with:

```
SELECT count(position_id) as count1, position_id 
FROM players1
where country_id = 3
group by position_id;
```

Getting result as:

```
position_id  count1
    1         54
    2         41
    3         39
    4         32
```

I want join 4 tables and want to get a result like:

```
position_id  count1   count2   count3   count4
    1         54        42       51       61
    2         41        40       49       59
    3         39        29       44       50
    4         32        21       37       47
```

Can you help me write this sql?

Comment: See UNION... but also consider whether one  table might be better than four

Comment: @Strawberry I tried Union but I can get 2 columns with union. I want to join tables by position_id column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have understand you question. Execute this Mysql query.

```
SELECT 
d1.position_id AS Positions_Id,
d1.count1 AS count1,
d2.count1 AS count2,
d3.count1 AS count3,
d4.count1 AS count4
FROM (
SELECT position_id, COUNT(position_id) AS count1
FROM players1
WHERE country_id=3
GROUP BY position_id) AS d1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT position_id, COUNT(position_id) AS count1
FROM players2
WHERE country_id=3
GROUP BY position_id 


) AS d2 ON d2.position_id = d1.position_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT position_id, COUNT(position_id) AS count1
FROM players3
WHERE country_id=3
GROUP BY position_id 

) AS d3 ON d3.position_id = d1.position_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT position_id, COUNT(position_id) AS count1
FROM players4
WHERE country_id=3
GROUP BY position_id 

) AS d4 ON d4.position_id = d1.position_id
```